# Parallel table - driven testing in go fails miserably

Tags: go, testing

I have the following test function

```golang
func TestIntegrationAppsWithProductionSelf(t *testing.T) {
    // here is where the apps array that will act as my test suite is being populated
    myapps, err := RetrieveApps(fs)
    for _, v := range apps {
        v := v
        t.Run("", func(t *testing.T) {
            t.Parallel()
            expectedOutput = `=` + v + `
`
            cmpOpts.SingleApp = v
            t.Logf("\t\tTesting %s\n", v)
            buf, err := VarsCmp(output, cmpOpts)
            if err != nil {
                t.Fatalf("ERROR executing var comparison for %s: %s\n", v, err)
            }
            assert.Equal(t, expectedOutput, buf.String())
        })
    }
}
```

The test fails, despite the fact that when I remove `t.Parallel()` (even keeping the sub-testing structure) it succeeds.

The failure (happens as said before only when `t.Parallel()` is incorporated) has to do with the fact that the values to be compared passed to assert are out of sync, i.e. the `assert` method compares values that it shouldn't)

Why is that? 
I also perform this cryptic re-assignment of the test suite variable (`v := v`) which I do not understand)

**edit**: Wandering if it was the usage of the `assert` method from [this](http://github.com/stretchr/testify/assert) package, I made the following substitution, nonetheless the end result is the same,

```golang
    //assert.Equal(t, expectedOutput, buf.String())
    if expectedOutput != buf.String() {
        t.Errorf("Failed! Expected %s - Actual: %s\n", expectedOutput, buf.String())
    }
```

Comment: I really don't understand the "close cause off-topic" votes...does this really seem like an out of software engineering scope question, whilst there are numerous irrelevant questions such as "why this thing fails on my mac" and "how to I spin up a VM on digital ocean?"...SO needs to take down/close votes more seriously; one can argue that the question is dumb or the author has not conducted extended investigation before asking, but HOW ON EARTH this question is out of scope?

Comment: The close reasons appear to be "It's seeking debugging help but needs more information..." (if you follow the help-center link, it's the very first bullet point presented) You didn't explain how or where the the tests fail, or provide a stack trace, race detector output, or even an [mre].There is an answer that is willing to start from the first principals for you, but expecting that level of service is not going to go far here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's dissect the case.

First, let's refer to [the docs on `testing.T.Run`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#T.Run):

> Run runs f as a subtest of t called name.
>   **It runs f in a separate goroutine** <…>

(Emphasis mine.)

So, when you call `t.Run("some_name", someFn)`, that `SomeFn` is being run by the test suite as if you would manually do something like

```golang
go someFn(t)
```

Next, let's notice that you do not pass a named function into your call to `t.Run`, but rather you pass it a so-called *function literal;* let's cite [the language spec on them](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals):

> Function literals are *closures:* they may refer to variables defined in a surrounding function. Those variables are then shared between the surrounding function and the function literal, and they survive as long as they are accessible.

In your case, it means when the compiler compiles the body of your function literal, it makes the function "close over" any variable its body mentions, and which is not one of the formal function parameters; in your case, the only function parameter is `t *testing.T`, hence every other accessed variable is captured by the created closure.

In Go, when a function literal closes over a variable, it does so by retaining *a reference* to that variable — which is explicitly mentioned in the spec as («Those variables are then **shared** between the surrounding function and the function literal <…>», again, emphasis mine.)

Now notice that loops in Go *reuse* iteration variables on each iteration; that is, when you write

```golang
for _, v := range apps {
```

that variable `v` is created once in the "outer" scope of the loop and then gets *reassigned* on each iteration of the loop. To recap: the same variable, whose storage is located at some fixed point in memory, gets assigned a new value on each iteration.

Now, since a function literal closes over external variables by keeping *references* to them — as opposed to copying their values at the "time" of its definition *into* itself, — without that funky-looking `v := v` "trick" each function literal created at each call to `t.Run` in your loop would reference exactly the same iteration variable `v` of the loop.
The `v := v` construct declares another variable named `v` which is *local* to the loop's body and at the same time assigns it the value of the loop iteration variable `v`. Since the local `v` "shadows" loop iterator's `v`, the function literal declared afterwards would close over that local variable, and hence each function literal created on each iteration will close over a distinct, separate variable `v`.

Why is this needed, you may ask?

This is needed because of a subtle problem with the interaction of loop iteration variable and goroutines, which is [detailed on the Go wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes#using-goroutines-on-loop-iterator-variables):
when one does something like

```golang
for _, v := range apps {
  go func() {
    // use v
  }()
}
```

A function literal closing over `v` is created, and then it's run with the `go` statement—in parallel both with the goroutine which runs the loop and with all the other goroutines started on the `len(apps)-1` other iterations.
These goroutines running our function literals all refer to the same `v` and so they all have a data race over that variable: the goroutine running the looop *writes* to it, and the goroutines running function literals *read* from it—concurrently and without any synchronization.

I hope, by now you should see the puzzle's pieces coming together: in the code

```golang
    for _, v := range apps {
        v := v
        t.Run("", func(t *testing.T) {
            expectedOutput = `=` + v + `
            // ...
```

the function literal passed to `t.Run` closes over `v`, `expectedOutput`,
`cmpOpts.SingleApp` (and may be something else),
and then `t.Run()` makes that function literal run in a separate goroutine, as documented,—producing the classic data race on `expectedOutput` and `cmpOpts.SingleApp`, and whatever else which is not `v` (a fresh variable on each iteration) or `t` (passed to the call of the function literal).

You might run `go test -race -run=TestIntegrationAppsWithProductionSelf ./...` to see the engaged race detector crashing your test case's code.

Comment: Any idea why in [this](https://gist.github.com/pkaramol/5a7fc1df2bf54dcbf1b11b267fa21cc6) test scenario, if I comment out `k := k` and `v := v` the `-race` flag does not detect any issues?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to post what actually worked, but (unless the question is closed) I will accept the answer that actually elaborates on it.

The problem was that the variable used to store the `expectedOutput` was declared with a declaration inside the `TestIntegrationAppsWithProductionSelf` function but outside the `for` loop (this is now reflected in the code snippet of the initial question).

What worked was to remove the `var expectedOutput string` statement and do within the `for` loop

```
    for _, v := range apps {
        v := v
        expectedOutput := `=` + v + `
`
        t.Run("", func(t *testing.T) {
            t.Parallel()
            cmpOpts.SingleApp = v
            t.Logf("\t\tTesting %s\n", v)
            buf, err := VarsCmp(output, cmpOpts)
            if err != nil {
                t.Fatalf("ERROR executing var comparison for %s: %s\n", v, err)
            }
            //assert.Equal(t, expectedOutput, buf.String())
            if expectedOutput != buf.String() {
                t.Errorf("Failed! Expected %s - Actual: %s\n", expectedOutput, buf.String())
            }
        })
    }
```